# SwiftUI Path is pixelated when in second Navigation View

Tags: ios, swiftui, path

I have a strange behavior on my SwiftUI app. I draw a `Path` with a linear gradient as stroke color.

This path is displayed like this in my view:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    LinePath(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
        .stroke(gradient, lineWidth: 3)
}
.frame(height:200)
.padding()
```

(`LinePath` struct extends `Shape` and draw the `Path`)
When this code is displayed on first view, it draws correctly:

[image: correct]

But if I display it in a second view after a NavigationLink, the drawn line is "pixelated":

[image: issue]

As it may be difficult to understand and there is quite lot of code (for a web page), I did a demo project you can [get here](https://apps.gander.family/testproject.zip).

To test it, you can open `testprojectApp.swift` and comment/uncomment parts:

```
ContentView() // <--- Uncomment this to get the issue
//SubView() // <--- Uncomment this and it works
```

If you call `SubView` (where this `LinePath` is drawn), it works. If you call `ContentView` that will display a button to navigate to `SubView`, it draws a pixelated line.

Notes:

- If I don't set a `height`, it is never pixelated (`.frame(height:200)`).
- If I don't use a gradient but a simple color (as `.blue`), it is never pixelated.

**EDIT**: I've found a "workaround", to redraw the line 0.01s after it appeared and change its height. It visually "works" but of course it is not a good method...

```
@State var height: CGFloat = 0
var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        LinePath(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
            .stroke(gradient, lineWidth: 3)
    }
    .frame(height:height)
    .padding()
    .onAppear() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            height = 200
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `.drawingGroup()` and it seems to resolve the issue without having to use the delay:

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    LinePath(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
        .stroke(gradient, lineWidth: 3)
}
.frame(height:200)
.padding()
.drawingGroup() //<-- here
```

Comment: Yes it works! It's a bit slower to display view but it is not pixelated anymore.

Comment: I’m not seeing a speed change at all, but I’m on an M1, so it’s pretty speedy in general.

Comment: Sorry, you're right! I was trying on my normal project that has much more data. Thank you for your help.